# How to get the time difference in talend?

Tags: talend

How to get the difference in time by comparing with the previous value and getting the result .Say for example 
There are 
2017-01-01 13:00:00
2017-01-01 13:15:00

I need the difference as 15 minutes after finding the difference,How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you'll have to use `TalendDate.diffDate(column1,column2,"pattern")` to get the time difference.
Then, if you want to compare current value with previous one (in the same column), you can set a sequence on your flow, it will help you identify which one is the previous value. Then, you'll just have to read twice your flow, and have an inner join between current sequence and current sequence -1 to get the currentDate and the previous Date.

First subjob :
    YourFlow -> tMap -> tHashOutput

In tMap, add a new "sequence" column to your field and use `Numeric.sequence("s1",1,1)`.
This way all lines will have an ID.

Then, read twice your Hash , and join flows on "sequence - 1"

```
tHashInput_1----|
                |--tMap--->Output
tHashInput_2----|
```

Put the TalendDate.diffDate() method in the output, using the two Dates fields.

Comment: For comparing i am using tMemorizeRows for getting the last value of the array but unfortunately i am not getting the previous value from the array , I am getting null as the output ,I dont know why i am not getting

Comment: so did you try the solution I provided ?

Comment: I have tried that ,Meanwhile i am also trying the otherways.Your solution is working

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative :

Start defining starting talend job execution time, this way (here in a tJava, but you can also use tSetGlobalVar component) :

```
globalMap.put("startDate", TalendDate.getDate("CCYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss"));
```

The following code is used later in the job inside a tJava :

```
String endDate = TalendDate.getDate("CCYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss");

long executionTime = format.parse(endDate).getTime() - format.parse(((String)globalMap.get("startDate"))).getTime();

System.out.println("Execution Time : "+(executionTime/(60*60*1000))+" Hour(s) "+(executionTime/(60*1000)%60)+" Minute(s) "+(executionTime/1000%60)+" second(s).");
```